# Remote File Browsing on Windows Server 2012 CORE

Tags: windows-server-2012

Is there a way to remotely browse files on SERVER-CORE?

I want to copy over some ISOs over for HYPER-V from the NAS so that I can boot them up in HYPER-V.

Not sure how to do that or how to browse and access files remotely.

Do I have to do this via powershell?

Comment: Hi Frank, I've only been able to do this before by mapping drives in Server Core to be able to browse network locations. in Command Prompt type 'Net Use *driveletter* *UNCpath*' and then browse to that drive letter should get you on...

Answer (score 1):

You can do so by [enabling WinRM](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/555966) on that server and then connect using powershell.

If you've installed before the file services than you'd be able to simply navigate to C$ share.
There are also a few more options I can think of, but they require 3rd-party utilities (like VNC or SSH Server).

In any case, you'll need to configure that on the server before you can access it..